# Heroku Postgres + Python: too many connections error

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build the application that get saved users timeline tweets on Twitter in Flask. But this error occurs.

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  too many connections for role "xxxxxxxxxxxx"

This program is working on my local server/environment, but not when I host it on Heroku, it breaks.

**app/__init__.py**

```py
# Initialized app
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
configure_app(app)

# Initialized database
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
db.init_app(app)

# Get timeline tweet
import main.get_tweet
```

**app/get_tweet.py**

```py
from flask import current_app
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

from main.database import save_tweet

import tweepy

def get_current_tweet():
    client_id = current_app.config['TWITTER_CLIENT_ID']
    client_secret = current_app.config['TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET']

    base_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/'
    user_timeline_url = base_url + 'statuses/user_timeline'

    users = fetch_users()    
    for user in users:
        try:
            twitter_profile = user.twitter_profile_info()

            oauth_token = twitter_profile.access_token
            oauth_verifier = twitter_profile.access_secret

            auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(client_id, client_secret)
            auth.set_access_token(oauth_token, oauth_verifier)

            api = tweepy.API(auth)
            user_tweets=api.user_timeline(screen_name=twitter_profile.screen_name, count=1, exclude_replies=False, include_rts=False)

            status = user_tweets[0]._json
            save_tweet(status, user)
        except:
            print(user.name + " has been errored.")

sched = BackgroundScheduler(standalone=True,coalesce=True)
sched.add_job(get_current_tweet, 'interval', minutes=10)
sched.start()
```

**app/database.py**

```py
def update_or_create_current_tweet(request, user):
    twitter_profile = user.twitter_profile_info()
    uid = request['id']
    url =  "https://twitter.com/" + twitter_profile.screen_name + "/status/" + str(uid)
    content = request['text']
    tweet = Tweet(
       uid=uid,
       user_id=user.id,
       url=url,
       content=content
    )
    db.session.add(tweet)
    db.session.commit()
    return current_tweet
```